# README.md file not shown on GitHub Overview

Tags: git, github, readme

I created my git repo locally, linked the upstream and pushed it to GitHub after creating a README.md file locally.

However, the GitHub overview panel doesn't detect the file and prompts me to create a new one. It does, however list the file and the commit message.

Any clues to why? I did match the case and extension.

Comment: Also make sure to make the repo private for Member mode, and public for Public mode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently GitHub doesn't detect empty README files and the workaround is to **populate the file**.

A similar issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2733

---

I do however feel that this shouldn't be the case, and as @mariusa said

> Or even better, stop checking if the file is empty or not.
>
> Either force developers to put correct documentation and make a check
> for this, or stop checking if file is empty, as one can easily put a
> word just to get rid of this (after googling why the heck it still
> gives the README.md not found after being there).